# Flutter: How to implement recaptcha for firebase auth plugin

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I wanna implement firebase auth method but it want me recaptcha when I pass recaptcha I face to this problem

```
E/flutter (19828): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'delegateFor' was called on null.
E/flutter (19828): Receiver: null
E/flutter (19828): Tried calling: delegateFor(container: "recptcha", onError: Closure: (FirebaseAuthException) => Null, onExpired: Closure: () => void, onSuccess: Closure: () => void, size: Instance of 'RecaptchaVerifierSize', theme: Instance of 'RecaptchaVerifierTheme')
```

Here is my code :

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber,
  RecaptchaVerifier(
    container: 'recptcha',
    onError: (e) {
      print(e);
    },
    onExpired: () => print("Expired"),
    onSuccess: () => print("Success"),
    size: RecaptchaVerifierSize.compact,
    theme: RecaptchaVerifierTheme.light,
  ),
);
```

Comment: for mobile app no need recaptcha verification just need in flutter web

Comment: but if I remove it another error occurred by the name of un implement recaptcha

Comment: which package do you use for phone varification

Comment: Firebase auth package

Answer (score 3):

````
var recaptchaVerifier = RecaptchaVerifier(
        container: null,
        size: RecaptchaVerifierSize.compact,
        theme: RecaptchaVerifierTheme.dark,
        onSuccess: () async {
          print('reCAPTCHA Completed!');
          setState(() {
            currentInput = "otp";
            _isLoading = false;
          });
        },
        onError: (FirebaseAuthException error) async {
          print("error");
          print(error);
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = false;
          });
          _scaffoldKey.currentState
              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.message)));
        },
        onExpired: () async {
          print('reCAPTCHA Expired!');
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = false;
          });
        },
      );
```
await _auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneController.text, recaptchaVerifier).then((confirmationResult) {
        // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
        // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
        setState(() {
          verificationId = confirmationResult.verificationId;
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
      });
```
````